# Need help about apache 2.4.46 configuration on rhel 7.2!!! (HTTPD_ROOT)

Tags: rhel, apache-httpd

The first time I installed Apache 2.4.46 from source downloaded on the Internet , I just run `./configure && make && make install`, so the default directories for this are :

```
ServerRoot = /usr/local/apache2
DocumentRoot = /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
```

However, my team-lead need to install with `ServerRoot=/etc/httpd` and

```
DocumentRoot=/var/www/html
```

Thus, I remove `/usr/local/apace2` folder and reinstall with command
`./configure --prefix=/etc/httpd --docdir=/var/www/html` and then, make && make install.

The problem is when I start apache, it has an error that:

```
 httpd: Could not open configuration file /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: No such file or directory
```

I then run `/etc/httpd/bin/apachectl -V` command and found out that the `HTTP_ROOT` is still associated with `/usr/local/apache`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /etc/httpd/bin/apachectl -V
    -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache2"
    -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache2/bin/suexec"
    -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
    -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
    -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
    -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
    -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Hence, my question is, how can I change this `PATH` for `HTTPD_ROOT` like this

```
HTTPD_ROOT=/etc/httpd
```

Thanks a lot for all your support, guys and I'll appreciate it!

Comment: RHEL has [Apache 2.4 available](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/445713) as a package. Why not use that?

Comment: @roaima apache 2.4.6 has a few common features missing. Eg it requires a separate option to tell where to use the intermediate TLS certificate instead of bundling it to the server certificate. BUT, there's RHEL Software Collections providing httpd (2.4.34 afaik). As it's RHEL (and not CentOS) it's a bit more difficult: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/472793 . That way one wouldn't have to figure out how to get SELinux to work with a local installation etc.

Comment: OK. Does `./configure --help` give you any suggestions for a suitable flag. Failing that do the installation instructions offer any suggestions?